# new Object.getClass()

Tags: java, oop, reflection, dynamic, jcombobox

Is there a way to make a new Object of the type of another?

Example:

```
Soldier extends Person
Accountant extends Person
```

Each subclass of Person has a constructor that accepts (BirthDate and DeathDate)

I have a method called prepPerson(Person) and it accepts a Person. I would like to have a JComboBox populated with Person objects of different types (Accountant, Soldier) that I call .getSelectedItem() and get back a Person object.

As I am only using those Person objects to populate the JComboBox menu how do I detect the type of person selected, make a new Soldier or Accountant object so that I can pass it to the prepPerson method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to have a finite number of selections, do this:

```
Person thePerson = null; // note, don't call variables theAnything... it's just bad

JComboBox theBox = new JComboBox(new String[]{"Accountant","Soldier","Programmer"});



// later

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == theBox) {
            String who = (String)theBox.getSelectedItem();
            if(who.equals("Accountant") thePerson = new Accountant();
            if(who.equals("Soldier") thePerson = new Soldier();
            if(who.equals("Programmer") thePerson = new Programmer();
        }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, you could also have `class PersonRole` as an element of your Person, as @Jan Zyka answered. In this case, you could do `if(who.equals("Accountant")) thePerson.addRole(new AccountantRole());` (Actually, in that case, I'd change `String who` to `String what`! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use either `instanceof` or create method `getType()` on `Person` which return enum - the type of the `Person`.

But when you start using `instanceof` in such situation you may consider to change the desing somehow.

Could you describe why do you need to distinguish them later?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to detect the type? You have a `Person` and you must pass a `Person` to the new method.

You are likely to find seperating Roles/Types from a Person useful.  This way any Person can have one or more roles which can change at any time.

Comment: I need the type so that I can get the appropriate person back so that I can call that class's constructor so that I can make a new object from that object to avoid having to write copy constructors for all those classes.

Comment: Could you have the classes Cloneable? (if all you want to do is copy them)  You can use reflection to get the constructor from the class but this is relatively ugly.